# False: if $C$ is closed then closure of interior of $C$ is equal to $C$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $C$ is a closed set in a metric space $(X,d)$, then $\overline{C^\circ} = C$

I know that this is false, but I'm having trouble coming up with a good
counterexample to show that it doesn't work. Ideas?

Edit:
Wow, the answers are so simple! Major brain fart... Thank you so much for input!

Comment: What have you tried? What would happen if $C$ were a closed set with **empty** interior? Can you think of such a set? What about a one-point subset of the real line?

Answer (score 6):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. A singleton $\{x\}$ is closed. But what is the interior of $\{x\}$? And the closure of that?

Answer (score 4):

$C=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$ is closed. $C^o=(0,1)$. $\overline{C^o}=[0,1]\ne C$